# Admob Add shown in Delay Time

Tags: android, admob

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
AdView adView;
InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3500425325579414/2869090680");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(
            "BD9386F17F7DE795B86B5BBBEDDF1095").build();

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            }
        }
    });

    Thread timerThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run();

            try {
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                ?????????????????????
            }

        }
    };
    timerThread.start();

}
```

}

I want to show my Admob add after my selected time.
I want to use a Thread to show my add in dealy.
But how i complite this i could not do it.
Even i tryed this

```
    Thread timerThread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run();

            try {
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                            interstitialAd.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    };
    timerThread.start();
```

But this is not working.
How i can do it in programatically.

Answer (score 2):

The problem I see is that you are *setting* the Adlistener after a delay instead of *showing* the ad after a delay.
Also you don't need to create a Thread for doing that, you can try this for example:

```
interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
                MainActivity.this.interstitialAd.show();
            } 
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Put this in your MainActivity onCreate method and get rid of the timerThread. This way you'll have your interstitial configured that it will show up 5 sec *after* the ad is loaded.

Note: From user a **user experience** point of view that is *not* such a good idea because you'll most likely end up annoying your users. The best practice is to show ads at natural breaks, like "level completed" etc.

Comment: Do not forget to dismiss the delayed ad in `Activity#onPause` to be sure that no attempt will be made to show it after the activity has been closed by user/OS.

Answer (score 1):

You **DON'T** want to show your interstitial ads at random (delayed or not) time within your app. Unless

1. You want really bad user ratings
2. You want Admob to disable your account.

Instead you should pick a suitable break point in your app and show the ad then.